# Dir command does not work as I want it to

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am supposed to write a batch file which would find files starting with letter `a` and end with the extension `.dll`.

Here is what I came up with:

```
@echo off
dir /b *.dll C:\windows\system32\ > dll.txt
dir /b a* C:\windows\system32\ > a.txt
```

My script does not work the way I want because it lists all the files from `system32` directory.

Can anyone help me fix it the way it should be?

Comment: I cannot believe your code lists *all* files. Anyway, have you ever considered the pattern `a*.dll`?

Comment: As I have written below, I expressed myself wrong. One list should contain .dll files from system32 folder and another list should contain only files from the same directory but starting with letter a.

Answer (score 2):

`dir /b *.dll C:\windows\system32\` lists all files that match `*.dll`, then all files that match `C:\windows\system32\` - that is, all files in that folder. The correct syntax for what you want to do is:

```
dir /b "C:\windows\system32\*.dll"
```

Same with the other line:

```
dir /b "C:\windows\system32\a*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this batch :

```
@echo off
Set Log=%~dp0Files_DLL.txt
CD /D %Windir%\system32\
Dir /b a*.dll>>%Log%
Start "" %Log%
```

Comment: I made a mistake in expressing myself. "a.txt" is supposed to contain only file names starting with letter a, and "dll.txt" is supposed to contain only files with .dll extension. I've just fixed it halfway to make at least .dll list work properly by adding find command. Now it looks like this 'dir /b *.dll C:\windows\system32\ | find ".dll" > dll.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

The command **DIR** supports multiple arguments for directory listings.

```
dir /b *.dll C:\windows\system32\ > dll.txt
```

This command line results in writing to file `dll.txt`

1. all non-hidden file and folder names matching in **current directory** the wildcard pattern `*.dll` **and**
2. all non-hidden file and folder names matching in directory `C:\windows\system32\` the default wildcard pattern `*`.

The next command line is:

```
dir /b a* C:\windows\system32\ > a.txt
```

This command line results in writing to file `a.txt`

1. all non-hidden file and folder names matching in **current directory** the wildcard pattern `a*` **and**
2. all non-hidden file and folder names matching in directory `C:\windows\system32\` the default wildcard pattern `*`.

But most likely wanted is writing to `dll.txt` all *.dll files in directory `C:\windows\system32\` and to `a.txt` all `a*` files in directory `C:\windows\system32\` with both times including also matching files with hidden attribute set. For that reason the command lines to use is:

```
dir %SystemRoot%\System32\*.dll /A-D /B >dll.txt
dir %SystemRoot%\System32\a* /A-D /B >a.txt
```

The option `/A-D` disables listing of directories (attribute not directory) matching by chance also the wildcard patterns and enabling listing of hidden files too.

For help on command **DIR** run in a command prompt window `dir /?`.

By the way: [Windows file system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) should be taken into account. The two command lines output to the text files the `*.dll` and `a*` files in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` if the batch file is executed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\` on 64-bit Windows because of batch file is started from within a 32-bit application.

The batch file below can be used to make sure getting the listings for Windows system directory according to Windows architecture which makes a difference on 64-bit Windows.

```
set "SystemFolder=%SystemRoot%\System32"
if exist "%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe" set "SystemFolder=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"
dir %SystemFolder%\*.dll /A-D /B >dll.txt
dir %SystemFolder%\a* /A-D /B >a.txt
```

The very special `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` redirector does not exist for 64-bit applications and so also not for batch files executed by 64-bit `cmd.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32\`. Please note that `Sysnative` is whether a directory nor a symbolic link. It is only possible to check if a file exists in `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`, but not if `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` itself exists.